# Multiple instances of programs allowed in Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, firewalls

I am new to Windows Firewall. While allowing a program through Windows Firewall, I found multiple entries present for Firefox and Java. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Are these entries using the same local/remote port and addresses?

Comment: How can I figure out that ?

Comment: Is that the full screenshot? what are the columns for the checkboxes? How did you arrive at this UI, which utility did you use?

Comment: @wei, It's for network types, 1st CB for Domain, Home and Private.

Comment: Which Windows version are you using? For Windows 7, you can try to invoke "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" from Run.  It should gives you the individual firewall rules with application names and related addresses/ports.

Comment: @wei, Does the above entries are reflected in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security tab ? What I want to know that why multiple entries are shown over here ?

Answer (score 1):

(IME) Java requires firewall exceptions for both TCP and UDP (and one firewall rule can't do both) so that's always two. In addition you can easily have/use more than one java programfile if you:

- use both `java.exe` for console mode and `javaw.exe` for GUI mode
- use both 32-bit and 64-bit java on 64-bit Windows
- use more than one major version (java 7 and java 8) and *possibly* with recent versions if you install new update(s) without replacing/removing earlier one(s)

Click the AdvancedSettings botton on ControlPanel / Firewall, or equivalently ControlPanel / AdministrativeTools / WindowsFirewall... or shortcut just run `mmc wf.msc`. Select InboundRules or OutboundRules as applicable (usually only Inbound as normal profiles implicitly allow programs Outbound), expand the Program column so you can see all of it, optionally drag columns around and/or click on the heading to sort, and you can more easily see the different programs.

Your two Firefox entries indicate the same executable in the entry *name*; it's conceivable the actual executables are different, and you should probably confirm, but the Mozilla people don't usually do silly things like that. But quite a few other properties of a firewall entry *can* differ, like protocol and address/port limitations, so scroll across and look for differences in any column(s) except Name.